# How to proxy the full url at nginx config?

Tags: nginx

I need to proxy locations `/v1/api/` to another url as:

```
location /api/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://frontend-api.preprod.my-app.com/api/v1/;
    }
```

however, at the mainstream, only the slug is received:

```
"GET /api/v1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"
```

because the upstream is configured to the specific domain `frontend-api.preprod.my-app.com`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name frontend-api.preprod.my-app.com;

   location / {
      root /var/www/frontend_api/current/public;

      # Turn on Passenger
      passenger_enabled on;
      passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/wrappers/ruby;
    }

}
```

the final result is 404, How would configure proxy_pass at the proxy server to send the host as well, so that the receiving server receives the full url instead of just the `/api/v1/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) explains the behavior:

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:

In your case, it means that the request URI is replaced by the `/api/v1/` URI specified in your `proxy_pass` directive.

If you want the URI to be passed as-is, then you need to do:

```
location /api/v1/ {
    proxy_pass http://frontend-api.preprod.example.com;
}
```

In this case, nginx uses the URI from the original request with the `proxy_pass` destination, as described by:

> If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

If you want to replace part of the request URI with different part, you need to use regular expression capture:

```
location ~ ^/source/path/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/destination/path/$1;
}
```

**Edit:**

To get the domain name of the original request passed to the upstream, one needs to set the `Host` HTTP header for the upstream request:

```
proxy_set_header Host       $host;
```

It is often useful to pass also the IP address of the visitor via header:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Comment: I tried `proxy_pass http://frontend-api.preprod.example.com;` but at the other side, I still get the same result. I don't have an issue with passing the slug, the issue is that the base url is not passed, only`/api/v1/` is seen at the receiving server, not `http://frontend-api.preprod.example.com/api/v1/`

Comment: You cannot pass the full URL as URI to the request to the backend. To get the host name, you need to use HTTP headers. I added an example to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried setting the Host header to $host, however, after that, I can't see the logs coming in the access.log of the receiver nginx!

Comment: Then your virtual host name setting in receiver nginx is not correct.

Comment: Thank you, there were an issue..